# Why Rundeck can't read custom remote node environment variables

Tags: rundeck

I tried to run some commands on a remote node to test if Rundeck can display its environment variables, and it's weired that Rundeck can read the default env vars but not mine : 
[image: command]

And result is :

[image: response]

I have defined my custom environment variables in different places (inside `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`) but no luck..
[image: custom var]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non interactive bash shell reads from .bashrc not .bash_profile. You might move your env var setting to .bashrc and source that file from .bash_profile.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.  `~/.bash_profile` is only sourced by bash when started in interactive login mode.